# How to use a custom conditional compilation symbol with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

In VS2017 I have defined a conditional compilation symbol 'APPSTORE'.

[image]

However the compiler is not recognizing the symbol.  Notice the APPSTORE code is disabled.

[image]

What is the proper way to use conditional compilation symbols?

Instead of a semicolon, I have tried a comma as well...

```
APPSTORE,__UNIFIED__;__MOBILE__;__IOS__;
```

Comment: Is the `FloodSearch.SDK` namespace in a different project from your iOS application project?

Comment: Yes, that's was the issue!  Thanks!

Comment: If you learned what is the cause, post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code I was trying to control was in a different assembly than the assembly where I set the conditional compilation symbol.  Once I entered the symbol in the correct project, it behaved as expected.  Thanks to @SushiHangover!